# regex to match a multi-line string

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry, for the badly named topic.
I'm looking for a efficient regular expression to match the following:

```
[2014-11-13 13:05:04] [path/to/class.instagram.php] Options: array (
  'client_id' => '',
  'client_secret' => '',
  'object' => 'tag',
  'object_id' => 'rwar',
  'aspect' => 'media',
  'callback_url' => 'http://www.localthisday.nl/instagram.callback.php',
)
```

I want it to be split up so it looks like this:

```
1. [2014-11-13 13:05:04]
2.[path/to/class.instagram.php]
3. Options: array (
  'client_id' => '',
  'client_secret' => '',
  'object' => 'tag',
  'object_id' => 'rwar',
  'aspect' => 'media',
  'callback_url' => 'http://www.localthisday.nl/instagram.callback.php',
)
```

I'm using this one at the moment:

`(\[(.*)\])(\s{1})(\[(.*)\])(\s{1})(.*)/gmi`

I know, it's not a very good one, that's probably why it doesn't work the way I want it to work.
Problem is; it's a multi-line string, and for some reason it does not work multi-line.
Could someone please help me?
I'm not that good in regular expressions unfortunately.

Comment: I would parse it instead. Maybe using regular expressions but not *one* regular expression...

Comment: Is `Options` key always an array ?

Comment: @aduch No, it can be pretty much anything; string, integer, array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the last `(.*)` with `([\S\s]*)` in your regex.

```
/(\[.*\])\s(\[.*\])\s([\S\s]*)/gmi
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bW3pG2/3)

See the captures at the right side in the above demo link.

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot easier than I expected. Spend like one hour trying all sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use non greedy quantifier:

```
(\[.*?\])\s(\[.*?\])\s(.*)/gmi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\]|\))
```

Try this.Replace by `$1\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/32

```
var re = /(\]|\))/gm;
var str = '[2014-11-13 13:05:04] [path/to/class.instagram.php] Options: array (\n \'client_id\' => \'\',\n \'client_secret\' => \'\',\n \'object\' => \'tag\',\n \'object_id\' => \'rwar\',\n \'aspect\' => \'media\',\n \'callback_url\' => \'http://www.localthisday.nl/instagram.callback.php\',\n)';
var subst = '$1\n';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```